# curl exec not working for me i used sms gateway url here

Tags: curl

i used below code
$varURL="here i given my sms gate way url"
    `<?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$varURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 95);
        $varResult  = curl_exec($ch);
   ?>`
but i put echo $varURL; and copy the url and paste in browser url i got sms success,but in curl exec its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing you are missing from the browser request is the User-Agent:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0");
```

Also, run the code with `VERBOSE` mode enabled so that you can see the things yourself.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
I added both lines mentioned on above after this line
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
still its not working for me

Comment: `still not working` type of response will not help you to solve your problem. At least I can't!!

Comment: $varResult = curl_exec($ch);
i put print_r($varResult);
no output i get
$varResult contains empty result